# Java how to compare Predicates

Tags: java, java-8, compare, java-stream, predicate

I have two prodicates :

```
Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate1 = NavigationCategoryModel.class::isInstance;
Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate2 = BrandCategoryModel.class::isInstance;
```

With and if statement , how can I identify which predicate am I using ? I'm trying to do something like this but obviously isn't compiling :

```
if(predicate1.equals(NavigationCategoryModel.class::isInstance)){
}

if(predicate1==NavigationCategoryModel.class::isInstance){
}
```

Any hint ? I'm quite new to Java 8 lambdas

This is the code of the Pojos (simple inheritance for test purposes):

```
public class CategoryModel {
}

public class NavigationCategoryModel  extends CategoryModel{
}

public class BrandCategoryModel extends CategoryModel {
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you try to compare at them? If they are same type object?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: I want to compare if they use the predicate of NavigationCategoryModel or BrandCategoryModel

Comment: I need to know which of the isInstance class is using

Comment: you've to test it against the argument and then only you'll know which predicate is applied

Comment: Have you tried `if(predicate1 instanceof NavigationCategoryModel)`?

Comment: @Liquidpie can you provide me an example of that please?

Comment: @KunLun yes , but its not working

Comment: Can you give more code(NavigationCategoryModel/BrandCategoryModel) for testing?

Comment: @NexussimLements `NavigationCategoryModel.class::isInstance;` is like method body for `predicate1`, you've to test it against an input to know that both predicate1 signifies such assertion

Comment: @KunLun I've updated my question with the code of the pojos.

Comment: @Liquidpie My English is not very good , can you provide me a visual example of your explanation to understand you better please?

Comment: Check my answer, maybe it helps you.

Comment: When you replace the declaration with the semantically equivalent `Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate1 = new Predicate<CategoryModel>() { public boolean test(CategoryModel o) { return o instanceof NavigationCategoryModel;} };`, will there be any way to find out that it is testing for `instanceof NavigationCategoryModel`? Would you expect `predicate1.equals(new Predicate<CategoryModel>() { public boolean test(CategoryModel o) { return o instanceof NavigationCategoryModel;} })` to evaluate to `true`? Is there any reason to assume that lambda expressions or method references behave different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `test` method on Predicates. And, you've to provide the object to perform validation instead of actual method reference

```
predicate.test(object)
```

Documentation: [Predicate#test](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-)

For your problem, you can test if predicate1 returns true when object is of type `NavigationCategoryModel` as below:

```
predicate1.test(new NavigationCategoryModel()) // returns true
```

Similarly, for `BrandCategoryModel`, use:

```
predicate2.test(new BrandCategoryModel()) // returns true
```

If you want to test that object matches either of two, you can combine both the predicates like:

```
predicate1.or(predicate2).test(new NavigationCategoryModel()) // returns true
predicate1.or(predicate2).test(new BrandCategoryModel()) // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

What you try is to find which implementation you use.

The only way is to use function `test` from `Predicate`.

```
true if the input argument matches the predicate, otherwise false
```

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate1 = NavigationCategoryModel.class::isInstance;
    Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate2 = BrandCategoryModel.class::isInstance;

    System.out.println("Predicate1 isNavigation: " + isNavigation(predicate1));
    System.out.println("Predicate1 isBrand: " + isBrand(predicate1));
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Predicate2 isNavigation: " + isNavigation(predicate2));
    System.out.println("Predicate2 isBrand: " + isBrand(predicate2));

}

public static boolean isNavigation(Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate){

    return predicate.test(new NavigationCategoryModel());

}

public static boolean isBrand(Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate){

    return predicate.test(new BrandCategoryModel());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like KunLun's solution, but I think you should add one more condition, for example

```
Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate1 = NavigationCategoryModel.class::isInstance;
Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate2 = BrandCategoryModel.class::isInstance;

Predicate<CategoryModel> predicate1Testing = NavigationCategoryModel.class::isInstance;

System.out.println("Is A NavigationCategoryModel Predicate? " + predicate1.and(predicate1Testing).test(new NavigationCategoryModel()));
```

Comment: I don't understand. What's the difference between `predicate1` and `predicate1Testing`? Not sure why it's an advantage to extend one with the other.

Comment: Hi @Scratte, the predicate1Testing maybe differently. In this question, the author would like to know which predicate is using? The predicate1Testing is an input to compare with the original predicate.